# Issue with fgets while loop

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

At the moment I have something like this:

```
while(fgets(i, sizeof(i), stdin)!=NULL) {
    printf("%s", i);
    printf("line%d - j", j);
    j++
```

Which produces something like:

```
line1
line1 - j
line2
line2 - j
line3line3 - j
```

The problem I have is that the final line that I grab does not produce a new line and the second print statement continues to print on the same line.

Does somebody know how to fix this so that it produces:

```
line1
line1 - j
line2
line2 - j
line3
line3 - j
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Does the final line in the file being read have a newline?

Comment: "Does somebody know how to fix this?" By printing "HERE SHOULD BE A NEWLINE!"?

Comment: @Jens Don't think so, It's just a .txt file with a paragraph of text.

Comment: @Olaf Should be clear now with the edit I made.

Comment: I actually gave you a hint with that already. To say it very clear: if a line does not end with newline, you have to print one explicitly. Or you always remove trailing newlines from the lines and print it explicitly.

Comment: Anyway, we can't see the actual text file, so we're just guessing, but yes, fgets reads a line from the textfile, and if the line in the textfile contains a newline, then so will the string. If it doesn't, it won't. No extra processing is taking place.

Comment: Right, I see what's wrong. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding a check if there's a new line at the end of the string:

```
if (strchr (line, '\n') != NULL) { 
    printf("%s", line); 
} 
else { 
    printf("%s\n", line);
}
```

There's also the much shorter version suggested by Mr Lister:

```
printf(strchr(line, '\n') ?"%s" :"%s\n", line);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put some '\n' at the end of each string you write with a printf.

```
 while(fgets(i, sizeof(i), stdin)!=NULL) { 
    printf("%s\n", i);
    printf("line%d - j\n", j);
    j++;
```

That should solve your problem.
Bye !

Comment: No, that would add another new line on top of any existing new line which would fix the last entry but mess up the formatting of the previous lines.

I fixed it by adding this:

  if (strchr (line, '\n') != NULL) {
   printf("%s", line);
  }
  else {
   printf("%s\n", line);
  }

Comment: @yezi3 Or, shorter, `printf(strchr(line, '\n') ?"%s" :"%s\n", line);` Also, you can post an answer to your own question and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `fgets()` may or may not including an ending `'\n'` for various reasons.
Suggest stripping it off if it is there.

```
while(fgets(i, sizeof(i), stdin)!=NULL) {

  // delete potential \n - this works if \n exists or not
  i[strcspn(i,"\n")] = 0;

  printf("%s\n", i);         // add \n
  printf("line%d - j\n", j); // add \n
  j++
}
```