# when reading strings from an input file into a 2d array how do you substitute \n with \0, i.e extra line of garbage is being printed

Tags: c

I have this code to scan the strings from a given .txt file into an array:

```
 void readSentences(char inputFilePath[], char inputSentences[][MAX_CHAR]) {
    const char *INPUT_FILE_PATH = inputFilePath;
    FILE *fp = fopen(INPUT_FILE_PATH, "r+");
    int lineNum = 0;
    while ( fgets( inputSentences[lineNum], sizeof(inputSentences[lineNum]),  fp ) != NULL ) {
        lineNum++;
    }
    fclose (fp);
}
```

The input file path is just a .txt file containing the names of countries, but when I try to print the array an extra line of nonsense is printed as below:

```
Hong Kong
Ecuador
Dominican Republic
Taiwan
Hong Kong
Taiwan
Australia
Hong Kong
Italy
Hong Kong
Ukraine
Republic of Irelandp7Þ♣'☻­§Ò♣'☻P☺þ♣'☻
```

> Code that prints the array from main

```
int main() {
   char array1[MAX_LINES][MAX_CHAR];
   char array2[MAX_LINES][MAX_CHAR];

   readSentences("..//inputFiles/input1.txt", array1);
   readSentences("..//inputFiles/input2.txt", array2);


    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LINES; i++) {
        printf("%s", array2[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with fgets while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669657/issue-with-fgets-while-loop)

Comment: How does the caller of `readSenetences` know how many lines were read? Perhaps you should return `lineNum`?

Comment: @IanAbbott for this particular project it is unnecessary for the user to know how many lines were read, it is also unnecessary for the array to even be printed I only printed it to ensure that it was being scanned correctly.

Comment: Can't say for sure without a [mcve], but it looks like you're trying to print out one more element of the array than was read from the file...

Comment: Oh, and that should be `foo[strcspn(foo, "\n")] = 0;` to remove the newline.

Comment: @Matthew Sorry I deleted an incorrect comment. It should have been `buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';`.

Comment: It would help if you showed the code that does the printing.

Comment: @IanAbbott I have added the code that prints the array (MAX_LINES is defined as 20)

Comment: So you are just printing whatever uninitialized contents is in the remaining part of the array when the text file contains less than `MAX_LINES` lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays `array1` and `array2` have not been initialized before they are passed to `readSentences()`. If `readSentences` reads less than `MAX_LINES` files, the unread rows of the array will still contain uninitialized junk. `printf("%s", array2[i]);` is printing that junk, leading to *undefined behavior*.

There are various ways to initialize the state of `array1` and `array2` to something sensible before passing them to `readSentences()`.

1. Initialize the array contents in the declaration:

```
    char array1[MAX_LINES][MAX_CHARS] = {0};
    char array2[MAX_LINES][MAX_CHARS] = {0};
```

2. Clear the array contents with `memset()`:

```
    memset(array1, 0, sizeof array1);
    memset(array2, 0, sizeof array2);
```

3. Set the array rows to empty strings with `strcpy()`:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LINES; i++) {
        strcpy(array1[i], "");
        strcpy(array2[i], "");
    }
```

4. Set the array rows to empty strings by assigning `'\0'` to the first element of each row:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LINES; i++) {
        array1[i][0] = '\0';
        array2[i][0] = '\0';
    }
```

---

It would be better for `readSentences()` to return the number of lines:

```
char inputFilePath[], char inputSentences[][MAX_CHAR]) {
    ...
    return numLines;
}
```

Then the loop in `main()` can print just the valid lines:

```
    nlines2 = readSentences("..//inputFiles/input2.txt", array2);

    for (int i = 0; i < nlines2; i++) {
        printf("%s", array2[i]);
    }
```

---

This has nothing to do with the title of the question, which is about substituting `'\n'` with `'\0'`, but that was a red herring. If you want to do that anyway, the usual trick is to use `strcspn` to find the index of the `'\n'` character if it is present, or the index of the end of the string if not. Either way, the character at that index can be changed to `'\0'`:

```
    while ( fgets( inputSentences[lineNum], sizeof(inputSentences[lineNum]),  fp ) != NULL ) {
        char *s = inputSentences[lineNum]; /* saves typing :-) */
        s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';
        lineNum++;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate you're help, initializing the array contents in the declaration makes the most sense in my case. I will remove this question as I see now that my question could be misleading as to what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify `readSentences` and return the actual number of lines read from the file, either via a return value, or via a pointer parameter and print only the number of lines actually read.

Not knowing how many lines have been read makes the reading completely usless. Whatever code needs to process the lines read for whatever purpuse *must know* the number of lines read.

Something like this:

```
void readSentences(char inputFilePath[], char inputSentences[][MAX_CHAR], int *nblines) {
  const char* INPUT_FILE_PATH = inputFilePath;
  FILE* fp = fopen(INPUT_FILE_PATH, "r+");
  int lineNum = 0;
  while (fgets(inputSentences[lineNum], sizeof(inputSentences[lineNum]), fp) != NULL) {
    lineNum++;
  }
  fclose(fp);
  *nblines = lineNum;
}

int main() {
  char array1[MAX_LINES][MAX_CHAR];
  int nblines1;

  char array2[MAX_LINES][MAX_CHAR];
  int nblines2;

  readSentences("..//inputFiles/input1.txt", array1, &nblines1);
  readSentences("..//inputFiles/input2.txt", array2, &nblines2);

  for (int i = 0; i < nblines2; i++) {
    printf("%s", array2[i]);
  }
}
```

There is still room for further improvment:

- you need to check if `fopen` fails and act accordingly.
- if the number of liens in a file is greater than `MAX_LINES`, you're out of luck and your array index will go out of bounds and you'll get undefined behaviour.
- the `//` in `"..//inputFiles/....` should probably be `/`.